# Does a function without a return statement always return null in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, nullable, non-nullable, flutter-future

The return type of the following function is `Future<File?>` and yet the compiler does not complain that there is no return value if the picker did not return a picture.

```
static Future<File?> takeImage() async {
    PickedFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      print('PHOTO TAKEN');
      return File(pickedFile.path);
    } else {
      print('NO PHOTO TAKEN');
    }
  }
```

Would it not make more sense if I had to return `null` if the picture wasn't taken?

Does a method without a return statement always return null?

The example above seams to suggest it, and something as simple as this compiles too.

```
static String? s() {}
```

Could some one clarify whats going on?

Comment: `void`
A special type that indicates a value that’s never used. Functions like printInteger() and main() that don’t explicitly return a value have the void return type.

Comment: read carefully [A tour of the Dart language](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) - section about `Functions`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink for pointing me in the right direction.

Straight from [the documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#return-values):

> Return values
> All functions return a value. If no return value is specified, the statement return null; is implicitly appended to the function body.

Answer (score 0):

> Does a method without a return statement always return null?

Yes, here's a simple example

```
Future<void> main() async {
  var str = await start();
  print(str);
}

Future<String> start() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
}
```

output:

```
null
```

Paste it into [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/dart) to see it work :)

Comment: It does not work for me running Dart 2.13.0.  It wont compile with the error: The body might complete normally, causing ‘null’ to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.